# Unable to select options from the drop down using protractor

Tags: protractor

I am going to write automation scripts for angular 4 application which uses primeng drop down .

The code is below for the drop down control.

```
<p-dropdown formcontrolname="CertificationsType" class="ng-tns-c4-13 ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" ng-reflect-auto-width="false" ng-reflect-options="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-name="CertificationsType">
     <div class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-dropdown-open" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <input class="ng-tns-c4-13" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" aria-label="Other Programming">
        </div>
       <label class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Other Programming</label>
        <div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
            <span class="ui-clickable fa fa-fw fa-caret-down" ng-reflect-klass="ui-clickable" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ng-trigger ng-trigger-panelState" ng-reflect-ng-class="ui-dropdown-panel ui-widget-co" style="display: block; z-index: 1008; top: 32px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="ui-dropdown-items-wrapper" style="max-height: 200px;">
               <ul class="ui-dropdown-items ui-dropdown-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset ng-tns-c4-13">
                   <li class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                       <span class="ng-tns-c4-13">Select Type</span>
                   </li>
           <li class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                        <span class="ng-tns-c4-13">Other Programming</span>
                        </li><li class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-13">Source Programming</span>
                        </li><li class="ng-tns-c4-13 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-13">Techinical programming</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-dropdown>
```

My Page Object file code is below.

```
//To return "Type" drop down field options 
getTypeFieldData(){

let type_dropdown = element(by.css('p-dropdown[formcontrolname="CertificationsType"]'));
let ul_element = type_dropdown.element(by.tagName('ul'));
let li_elements= ul_element.all(by.tagName('li'));
    return li_elements;         
}
```

My Spec file code is below.

```
//Testcase 19 : To click on every option in the 
    //"Type" drop down 
    it('To click on every option in the Type drop down',()=>{
        //To click on every element of the "Type" drop down field content
        let list=page.getTypeFieldData();

                 list.each(function(options,index){

                             options[index].click();
                            browser.driver.sleep(5000);
                })
        });
```

After executing the code it is displaying below error message.

```
should test certificate tab To click on every option in the Type drop down
```

- Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Can any one help me in solving this issue

Comment: list.each(function(options,index){=> here options parameter having a single element not array of elements. so, instead of using options[index].click() try like options.click();

Comment: @Suresh Salloju After done modifications you mentioned in the comment it is displaying below error.
 Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x
86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Usually one needs first to click the element, that holds the dropdown, to open the selection list.

Also because of your stale element reference error I'll add [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Try this code:

```
//Testcase 19 : To click on every option in the 
//"Type" drop down 
it('To click on every option in the Type drop down',()=>{
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var dropdownElement = $('p-dropdown[formcontrolname="CertificationsType"] div.ui-dropdown');
    //To click on every element of the "Type" drop down field content
    let list=page.getTypeFieldData();
    list.each(function(option){
        //wait for the element to be visible and click the dropdown element to open selection
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dropdownElement),5000);
        dropdownElement.click();
        //wait for selection to be visible and click the value to select
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(option), 5000);
        option.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        })
    });
```

**UPDATE**

There was a typo in my "dropdownElement" selector. Instead of `ui-dropdown` it should be `div.ui-dropdown` (was a wrong use of CSS Selectors - fixed now in above code).

Should there be a message like "element not clickable, other element would receive the click", adjust "dropdownElement" to select that element.

Comment: @Emst Zwingli Thanks for your reply . I followed your comment . Now it is displaying --- invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified error message . Can you help  how to return the above drop down list . i tried with lot of ways but every time it is displaying invalid selector validation message. I am unable to access the list tag elements